# Custom android app installation

Tags: android

During a beta stage I need to be able to send out updates without going through the android store.  I have found a couple of posts regarding this, but none of them seem to work for me.  The file itself downloads fine, but for both alternatives I get an error of:

08-09 16:31:20.411: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(906): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://localhost:4567 typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }

Any ideas?

*Android*

```
// first way
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://localhost:4567"));

// second way
// Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://localhost:4567"), 
//                      "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

*Sinatra*

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/" do
  content_type "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
  attachment('agatha_v4.0.apk')
  file = File.open("agatha.apk", "rb")
  response.write(file.read)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File
                    (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the /download/app.apk is of course where you saved it when you downloaded it

Comment: Agreed. Android only supports `file:///` and `content://` schemes for installing APKs.

Comment: so the answer is you *have* to download the file, then install it.  When I do that and try to install the file I get an error message of "there is a problem parsing the package", even though I have checked if there is something wrong with the downloaded file by successfully installing it after copying it to the device.

Comment: IIRC I had a similar problem, and eventually discovered it was the host was not configured with application/vnd.android.package-archive. I could be wrong about the exact cause, but I remember that error and that we worked through it. The code I posted is the live code that installs the downloaded APK

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me on the Android side.  As was mentioned by Pyrodante you have to download the file first.  The other gotcha that I found was the file had to be set as MODE_WORLD_READBALE (MODE_PRIVATE) failed for me.

```
final String APP_FILE_NAME = "agatha.apk";
HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://10.10.100.113:4567");

try {
    HttpResponse response = http.execute(request);
    InputStream fileStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(APP_FILE_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = fileStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    fileStream.close();
    output.close();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(APP_FILE_NAME)), 
                       "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```